# Find MySql Credentials in Classic ASP site

Tags: mysql, vbscript, asp-classic

I'm a .NET developer and not familiar with how classic ASP sites are configured. I have to migrate an old Classic ASP site to a new server but can't find the database credentials in the code. The only reference I can find is below.

```
Dim Connect
Set Connect = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Connect.Open "MySQL"
```

Have tried searching for standard components you would expect to find a connection string but come up with nothing.

Is there anywhere else I should be looking? Is there maybe some configuration in the server itself that will hold the credentials?

I realise this is a little vague but would appreciate any help you can offer.

Thanks

Comment: You should find the settings for this connection (named "MySQL") in ODBC data sources in control panel (or if it is on a web server there should be settings somewhere in your web-based website control panel). Unfortunately you will only be able to get the connection URL and username as the password will not be visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably an ODBC data source stored in the Windows registry on the old server.

See http://classical-asp.blogspot.nl/2010/08/opening-connection-with-odbc.html (chapter 'Saving Connection String in Windows Registry')